# Error: could not decode result data ethers js

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat

```
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import Election from '../../artifacts/contracts/Elections.sol/Election.json';

export default async function getContract() {
  const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider((window as any).ethereum);
  const contractAddress = '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266';
  const accounts = await provider.send('eth_requestAccounts', []);
  const signer = await provider.getSigner(accounts[0]);
  const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, Election.abi, signer);
  const rx = await contract.getCandidates();
  console.log(contract);
  return contract;
}
```

This is my contract and i want to view the candidates that i added i tried many ways to access,
but always same error

````
 mapping(uint256 candidateCount => Candidate) public candidates;
 function getCandidates() public view returns (Candidate[] memory) {
        Candidate[] memory allCandidates = new Candidate[](candidateCount);

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < candidateCount; i++) {
            allCandidates[i] = candidates[i];
        }

        return allCandidates;
    }
}```
And the error is  Error: could not decode result data (value="0x", info={ "method": "getCandidates", "signature": "getCandidates()" }, code=BAD_DATA, version=6.6.2)
I also tried `contract.candidates(0)` same error
````